# Build Android Homescreen Widget with unity3d

Tags: android, android-widget, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make android homescreen widget with unity3d.

If i use unity3d's android-plugins well, i can make it.

But I can't figure it out how. And there's no guide about it at all.

I want to make widget not just act like short-cut widget,

but player CAN play the game through in homescreen.

Even I don't know that I'm wasting my time to do impossible thing.

Anyone help me how?

Comment: can you please tell me which plugins you used to create widget in unity 3D?

Comment: @ManojBalajiM it is not possible now. widget now can only support limited types of view.